# Taylor Series First Order Method for $x' = x-2t$ with $x(0) = 0$ given:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, power-series

With the step sizes h = 1, 1/2, 1/4

My solution for all step sizes came out to be zero and not sure if I am doing this right.

Since this is first order taylor series method, I'll be using: $x_{n+1}$ = $x(n) + hx'(n)$ when $x(0) = 0$.

So because x'(0) = 0, no matter what step size I use, I end up getting 0.

Comment: Yes, you have $ x(0+1(h))\approx x_1=0$ but continue on to approximate $x(0+2(h))\approx x_2=0+h\cdot x'(h)=h(0-2h)=-2h^2$.

Comment: but if i am to only solve to approximate x(1), it would just end at the first step correct?

Comment: No... if you want to approximate $x(1)$ and you use only one step, of size $h=1$, then yes it finishes after one step. If you use two steps, so $h=1/2$, you get $x(1)\approx -1/2\neq 0$.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is correct. You can check it  by direct method too.

$x'(t)-x=-2t$;  $x(0)=0$ is Linear first order DE, whose solution is easily obtained as:

$x(t)=2t+2-2e^t$. Expanding $e^t$ by Taylor's series;

$x(t)=2t+2-2\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+...\right)$ which on approximating up to first order term(*as you are using Taylor's series method of first order or Euler's method*) gives $x(t)=2t+2-2(1+t)=0$ which is the same as obtained by you.

Comment: can't understand the downvote. However, I have edited it to make it more clear for OP. If still have some issues then please tell me.

Comment: I downvoted because this isn't Euler's Method...

Comment: Indeed the Euler's method is first order Taylor's series method. However, modified Euler's method gives better approximation.